# moving magento 2X from local server (My mac) to new domain and server (with control panel)

Tags: magento2, server-setup, domain

Im having trouble moving my existing site from my computer to a server,
I tried moving all the files to the public_html folder in the new server, changed the info on the server on the file env.php and the directory in phpadmin (On my original DB i dont have the design/head/includes option) to the new domain but nothing comes up when i enter new domain in the browser. I also deleted all the files in the var/cache folder.
No errors or anything, its like nothing really happened.
Is there anything additional i need to do to setup the account?

Comment: Sounds like you took the correct steps although I've had trouble moving sites and getting them working 100% locally vs on a server. Are you sure the domain is set up properly? Could you navigate to a test.html file using the domain name with no problem? Permissions could and often are an issue also (see var/cache and pub/static). Static content might need to be generated. I could probably think of more things

Comment: Would you say the most time productive solution would be to install a new instance of magento on the new sever and then try to import the modules I created?

Comment: I wouldn't think so and I don't see an advantage. I just cloned a site after commenting yesterday and all I had to do was zip, copy/move, unzip, clone database, change env.php to new db, change core_config url setting to new domain, and finally delete caches and static content. The site worked as expected, however this was the same server so that makes life easier. Nonetheless, it was pretty straightforward, so you may have something weird going on. I zipped up the entire contents of my websites root includin caches (which like I said I ended up deleting)

Comment: I'll add that doing the setup process may show you if a clean install works and might provide helpful errors, so in that sense I can say it might be a good idea. Also now that I put more thought into it, recreating the site might show you were things are going wrong, ie a specific module.

Comment: what error does your browser show? did you change the base_url setting?

Comment: It didn't show any errors